# Cannot locate node

Tags: ros, c++, rosbuild, node, tutorials

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have been following the following tutorial : "urdf/Tutorials/Using urdf with robot_state_publisher", but when I run "roslaunch r2d2 r2d2.launch", I have the following error: "cannot locate node of type [r2d2/state_publisher]".

I have to admit that I overlooked the statement "(throughout this example, we assume package name "r2d2" and node name "state_publisher")", so I have no file corresponding to a state_publisher. What's the solution?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/70348/cannot-locate-node/) by [Flavian](https://answers.ros.org/users/5572/flavian/) on ROS Answers with karma: 112 on 2013-07-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to have a look at the [launch file xml format for node](http://www.ros.org/wiki/roslaunch/XML/node). The line

`<node name="state_publisher" pkg="r2d2" type="state_publisher" />`

is likely your problem. Change `type="state_publisher"` to `type="<insert your executable name here>"`

---

Originally posted by [thebyohazard](https://answers.ros.org/users/1483/thebyohazard/) with karma: 3562 on 2013-08-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Carrie Yan](https://answers.ros.org/users/30264/carrie-yan/) on 2017-06-06**:
I use .cpp to write my state_publisher and I change the type="" to type = "state_publisher.cpp" in my launch file, but it still reports
ERROR: cannot launch node of type [r2d2/state_publisher.cpp]: can't locate node [state_publisher.cpp] in package [r2d2]

Please help. Thanks

**Comment by [thebyohazard](https://answers.ros.org/users/1483/thebyohazard/) on 2018-10-10**:
I'm just seeing your message. In the future, you should ask a new question and link to related questions in your question to get better help. Usually a file with a .cpp extension contains code and a binary will not have an extension. Use whatever the add_executable argument is in your CMakeLists.txt